# Object of abstract class is not allowed

Tags: c++, oop

I have this hierarchy and I'm trying to create an IServer connection. But it says object of abstract class is not allowed.

here are the classes and the error code is commented.

```
struct IServerConnection : public CImplRingRefPtr<IServerConnection>, virtual public IRefPtr
{
    virtual IServerData*                    CreateData(void) = 0;
    virtual IServerData*                    Request(void) = 0;
    virtual int                             Send(const IServerData *data) = 0;
};


struct ImplWFSConnection : public S3W::IServerConnection

{
private:
    OGRDataSource *m_wfs_t;
public:
    ImplWFSConnection() {}
    ~ImplWFSConnection() { OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource(m_wfs_t); }
    void                         Open(const char * url);
    bool                         QueryLayer(const char* layer);
    int                          Write(S3W::IWFSData *data);
    S3W::CRefPtr<S3W::IWFSData>  Read(void);


};




S3W::IServerConnection*   ImplMapServer::OpenWFSConnection(const char *url)
{
    if (!m_url)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else


   // connection_ptr->Open(m_url);

    return new ImplWFSConnection(); /error
}
```

Comment: Implement your pure virtual ( = 0) functions in the inheriting classes.

Comment: Why are you instantiating a derived class in the base class? Base class shouldn't be dependent on the derived classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Abstract classes are not meant to be instantiated. Hence the name "Abstract"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `IServerConnection` `CreateData`, `Request`, and `Send` are [pure virtual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) methods, that you must implement in your derived class before creating instance of that derived class.